# Waiting for a promise to resolve in AngularJS before continuing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have, in my angular `app.run()` method a call to an API to get some data, which is then attached to the `$rootScope` - the app needs this data in various places, so this seems to make sense to me as the place to get it.

Code is:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers'])

.run(['$templateCache', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$modalStack', 'appInit', function ($templateCache, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams,$modalStack, appInit) {

        // set loading to 0 for loading mask
        $rootScope.loading = 0;

        var globalPromise = appInit.getGlobal();//

        //var globalPromise = appInit.getGlobal();
        globalPromise.then(function (data) {                          

            // attach globalJSON to rootScope
            $rootScope.globalJSON = data;

        });

    }]);
```

so, I need the `globalPromise.then()` to be fulfilled before the rest of the application can run.

The issue I have is that sometimes the `globalPromise` takes a little longer to return than it takes some of the controllers to execute and build the templates - and in these cases some directives in the template need that `$rootScope.globalJSON` to be available. when its not, those directives & anything else needing it, error out.

Is there a way to pause the app until that promise has been fulfilled? Or should I be separating this out of angular and bootstrap angular after?

Comment: `$rootScope.$state = $state; $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;` why are you doing this?

Comment: That's needed in other areas - didn't post every single line of code, though that part has nothing to do with my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the most elegant, but I had come up with a solution to a similar issue in my application where I wanted to retrieve i18n resource bundles from the server on application load.

The basic idea is that while your request is asynchronous, obtaining the promise is synchronous. If you setup placeholder values on that object you can at least fake the references you need until they finally arrive. From there the data binding of AngularJS is leveraged to update the bindings to the actual results of the promise.

```
var globalPromise = appInit.getGlobal();//

globalPromise.then(function (data) {                          

  // attach globalJSON to rootScope
  $rootScope.globalJSON = data;

});

angular.extend(globalPromise, { /* insert your placeholder object data here */ });

$rootScope.globalJSON = globalPromise;
```

I am making an assumption that the data you are fetching is meant as data that will be handled by Angular's binding mechanisms (thus being able to update bindings when you get the proper globalJSON).

Comment: Thanks Rich, that will do nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the fact that you have solved an issue I want to share solution that I found to almost exactly the same issue.

On sturtup of an application I had to use `$http` service to get some data, and on success callback save this data into the service, that have been used by several controllers. However, sometimes this async call wasn't fast enough to complete before using of its data. To solve it I had to use `$broadcast` service.

That is my service looked like (in CoffeeScript):

```
app.factory 'MyService', ($http, $rootScope) ->
  myData = {}
  service =
    getData: ->
      myData

    setData (val) ->
      myData = val
      $rootScope.$broadcast('myData:updated', val)

    fetchData: ->
      $http.get "/url/to/data"

  service
```

And all I have to do in the controller, is to wait for `'myData:updated'` event:

```
app.controller 'MyCtrl', ($scope, Task) ->
  $scope.$on 'myData:updated', (event, data) ->
    $scope.myData = data
    # do whatever you like with that data
```

Hope it will help someone!